# How to write Clean Code in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to know how to write a clean code in CakePHP?
Definitely something like the book "Clean Code, A handbook of Agile Software Craftmanship by Robert Martin"

What is a cleaner way to write a controller, a model, and a view? How to handle inline javascripts the cleaner way?

I ask this questions because I do have managed cakephp application and it is currently bloated. We didn't wrote it with the clean code technique in our mind. So now we are having a hard time extending it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[ This question migth be closed ]

A few tips:

- You should think first on your data model.. normalized tables, correct models and relations.
- **respect MVC** and try using cake's ORM instead of doing `$model->query()` all the time.
- [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Make your code reusable, even if you're not planning to reuse it right now. Create elements, helpers, components and functions.
- try to use Cake Tools. i.e use the Session object instead of $_SESSION, the Cache Class, the Set Class, etc.
- [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Avoid unnecessary complexity

in my experience:

- I dont use cake's inline javascript.. I'd rather create Mootools Classes, i find it cleaner and much more flexible.
- I dont like Plugins, because I end up searching for hours for a plugin that can exactly what i want, and usually i dont find it.. and when I find it, it takes more time to understand how to install it and test it... and if they ask me to modify something I have to spend even more time trying to understand how the plugin works... for me, it's faster if I create my own tools and plugins.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.. It really helpful. I don't know what's wrong with this question as admin closes it. Is it not a question? Is it not helpful for everyone? I started hating stackoverflow.

Comment: it was closed because this might be subject of debate,for example, some people would say "use plugins" others will say "no, don't use plugins".. and Stackoverflow is a Question-Answer site, not a forum. Check the Faq to see what type of question should be asked here http://stackoverflow.com/faq =) cheers